# Convert String date with seperator "T" to Java.sql timestamp in Java

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I am trying to convert java `String date` into `java.sql.Timestamp`. I am able to convert this by using `SimpleDateFormat` with `String date` value as `"2021-01-07 02:02:16.172"`, but when trying with the value as `"2021-08-04T00:00:00.000"` with seperator `'T'`, it gives me error. Below is the java code:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        
        //String date = "2021-08-04T00:00:00.000Z";// How to convert this?
        
        String date = "2021-01-07 02:02:16.172";// conversion successful
        
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
        
        Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
        
        System.out.println(timestamp);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");` would be the old style

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @g00se (1) Please don’t advise the use of `SimpleDateFormat`, you’re doing people a bad favour. (2) Beware of the difference between `hh` and `HH`. Your formatter is not correct.

Comment: I'm not "advising" it. As you can see, I said it was the "old style"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the modern API for dates, times and related information (like offsets from UTC): `java.time`

`String`s in different formats need to be handled differently:

- your first example `String` is formatted in ISO standard, so it can be parsed without defining a custom format. The parsing implicitly uses a `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`, which will result in an `OffsetDateTime`
- your seconds `String` lacks the `'T'` between date and time as well as an offset, that means you can just directly parse it to a `LocalDateTime`

`java.sql.Timestamp` got methods for conversion to `java.time` classes, at least to/from an `Instant` and a `LocalDateTime`. Since an `Instant` is a well defined moment in time, you can derive it from an `OffsetDateTime`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // your two example datetimes
    String isoDateTime = "2021-08-04T00:00:00.000Z";
    String customDateTime = "2021-01-07 02:02:16.172";
    // you will need a custom formatter for the second one
    DateTimeFormatter customDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    // parse the Strings to java.time objects
    // ISO standard, no extra formatter needed for the first one
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(isoDateTime);
    // the second one requires the formatter defined above
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(customDateTime, customDtf);
    // convert them into Timestamps
    Timestamp tsOne = Timestamp.from(odt.toInstant());
    Timestamp tsTwo = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt);
    // and print them
    System.out.println("First Timestamp:  " + tsOne);
    System.out.println("Second Timestamp: " + tsTwo);
}
```

The output of this is

```
First Timestamp:  2021-08-04 02:00:00.0
Second Timestamp: 2021-01-07 02:02:16.172
```

This would be the new style...

Comment: I strongly recommend using `java.time` as this answer demonstrates. The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");
```

would be the old style

Comment: g00se - I did not like this answer. I have seen you writing good answers and I wish you continue doing so. There are two problems with this answer: (1) Use `HH` which is used for 24-hour format or use `hh:mm:ss.SSS a` where `hh` is used for 12-hour format and `a` is used for am/pm marker. (2) Do not use outdated and error-prone `SimpleDateFormat`.